# Why my divs are not arranged well in page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to arrange a html page using bootstrap functionality, but a div is at the top of the page and the other divs are at the bottom when I put them in a container. What is the proper way to arrange a page using bootstrap ?

This is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Settings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="icon-bar" style="float: left">
    <div class="employee"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></div>
    <div class="employee"><a href="summary.html"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a><!--Summary--></div>
    <div class="employee"><a href="planDetails.html"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a><!--Plan details--></div>
    <div class="employee"><a href="newRequest.html"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i></a><!--Company holidays--></div>
    <div class="employee"><a href="teamCalendar.html"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i></a><!--Team calendar-->
    </div>
    <div id="manager"><a href="pendingRequests.html"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"><span
            class="badge badge-notify hidden"></span></i></a><!--Pending requests--></div>
    <div id="hr"><a href="settings.html"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a><!--Settings button--></div>
    <div class="employee"><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></a></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <a href="adduser.html" class="btn-success btn">Create user</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="addLocation" class="btn-success btn">Create location</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="addRole" class="btn-success btn">Create role</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="addDepartment" class="btn-success btn">Create department</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="addOfficialHoliday" class="btn-success btn">Add official Holiday</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4 id="successMessage"></h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="locationModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Location name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="locationForm">
                    <input type="text" required='' id="locationName" name="name"/>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="locationBtn" value="Add new location"/>
                        <div id="alert" style='float: left; color: red'></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="roleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Role name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="roleForm">
                    <input type="text" required='' id="roleName" name="name"/>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="roleBtn" value="Add new role"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="departmentModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Department name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="departmentForm">
                    <input type="text" required='' id="departmentName" name="name"/>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="departmentBtn" value="Add new department"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<!--Include jQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.serializeObject.min.js"></script>
<!--Include js created for this page-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/settings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/notify.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is how it is arranged: [image: bootstrap problem]

Comment: Try change `<div class="icon-bar" style="float: left">` to `<div class="icon-bar" style="postion:absolute; left:0;">`

Comment: Without showing applied CSS we can't tell you what's wrong. Maybe it's because of left side menu

Comment: @Justinas there is no other css ( as you can see from `HTML` code ) except navbar,css

Answer (score -1):

because you've put them all in a separate `row`. what you need to do is, put them in the same `row` and also, your `col-xs-12` doesn't really do anything here to make it in a row. so you need to specify in your html that you want the buttons to be inline on larger screens like desktops.
if you want your buttons in a `row` on desktop, you need to put them in rows that'd fit. 
let's say you have 6 buttons. then you can use `col-md-2` as 12/6 = 2. or depending upon the length of these links/buttons you can change x in `col-md-x`.

here. [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/74uXte5Me6It6bb52P3k?p=preview) will show what i mean. you might have to enlarge the preview panel.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <a href="adduser.html" class="btn-success btn">Create user</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <button id="addLocation" class="btn-success btn">Create location</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <button id="addRole" class="btn-success btn">Create role</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <button id="addDepartment" class="btn-success btn">Create department</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <button id="addOfficialHoliday" class="btn-success btn">Add official Holiday</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h4 id="successMessage"></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-xs-12` -> doing that cell is as long as container.

Comment: Yeas. It's me. I've read all the post. And I would like to say, that you are wrong saying that `col-xs-12` does nothing on desktop - this is first. If you will look into css of `bootstrap` you will see, that it's working ok on desktop . And `col-xs-12` does nothing ONLY if there are other classes that working on bigger displays, as `col-md-x` or `col-lg-x`

Comment: And probably - this is not caused by `bootstrap`, byt left navi menu. And -> main problem that divs are at the end of page.

Comment: Col-xs-12 will work on desktop as well as on mobile too.

Comment: ok. i get where you're coming from. i'll update what i meant.